# how to close a thread which is doing IO operation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, io

I am having a scenario :

I have a thread which is calling a method where i use Default HTTP client to execute a request.  for getting the response I open an InputStream and use a Buffred Reader to read the stream.

While(s = buffer.readline .... )

Inside the while loop i keep looking at the response and see for a string " Hello " ...If i get the string i send the response object back ..

1. The While loop executes till i get the string
2. The while loop executes till i press the back key ( android )

Now the scenario works for my 1st point.  But i face issue in the 2nd point.

When i press back key, i need to stop my thread.

but i am not able to do it. I tried :

- thread.destroy
- thread.interrupt
- thread = null

None of the above works. In fact my thread is always running...

I am not clear if the issue is with Thread or the issue is with the While loop of the stream.

Because i see that the while loop is executing always..

Please help me the best way i can solve this issue...Whether close the thread or close the stream.

Please help me find way to close the stream and close the thread.

Comment: Could you please post your Thread code? :)

Answer (score 0):

thread.destroy() is deprecated. Do not use it.

The safest way to stop an IO bound thread is by interrupting it.

The thread's logic must cooperate by (1) checking for isInterrupted() status and
(2) catching InterruptedException exception.

It is important that both #1 and #2 above will be handled. interrupt()ing a
thread can in some occasions result in exceptions and in others in setting of
status with no exception!

A safe thread implementation goes like this:

```
class MyThread {
    private volatile boolean wasStopped;
    public void run() {
       try {
           while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !wasStopped) {
               do_thread_work();
           }
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           return; // gracefully stop thread
       }
    }

    public void gracefullyStop() {
        wasStopped = true;
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

To stop the thread call

```
   thread.gracefullyStop();
```

This pattern will work fine as long as the thread logic function (do_thread_work)
will not internally catch & dismiss InterruptedException. Be aware.

You will see other implementations that rely solely on isInterrupted() check 
without the additional wasStopped flag. I think this is a bad practice. 

 Why?
Because if the interrupt() was raised while the thread was in a waiting mode
i.e. inside functions wait() join() or sleep(), the thread will indeed be woken, 
but its interrupted status **will be set to false**.

Good luck.